# Granting access to master.sys.xp_dirtree SQL

Tags: sql-server

There may be an answer to this somewhere else on here, but I can't find it.

My organization uses a EHR called TIER that has a SQL back-end. One of the features of the EHR is that you can "scan" a document to a folder on the network with the unique ID of a row in a table on the server. Then from the EHR, you can open a record from the table and then it links to the documents in the folder with the same Unique ID.

An example may be helpful - In the EHR I create a document (a row in the ScannedFormTable) with unique ID of 100. I then "scan" (basically attaching or copying) a pdf or other document into a folder on the network (say D:\ScannedDocuments) with the name of 100, so abc.pdf is now in D:\ScannedDocuments\100. Then from the document in the EHR, I can open the pdf. However, without opening the document to check I can't see if there is any file in the ...\100 folder.

Through some googling, I found that using master.sys.xp_dirtree (and "Undocumented" procedure I think) I can have the EHR "see" the name of files "attached" to the documents. The issue is that I can run this stored procedure from SSMS, but can't from the EHR itself. I have tried to figure out a way to grant security permission for the user in the EHR to run the procedure vs running the script in the background on the server at regular intervals.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. As you may have noticed from the number of " used, I am a self taught SQL user who is better at googling than actually understanding the intricacies of the language.

Comment: I was better able to troubleshoot and the issue is with granting access to the xp_dirtree stored procedure. If I run it as a user with sysadmin server role, then it works, if not, it doesn't. I am trying to grant access to the procedure to the "Public" server role, but even though that grant seems to be there, it still doesn't work. Any ideas of how to get past this?

Comment: Figured it out. Gave one principal user sysadmin server role, then ran stored procedure as that user :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that using master.sys.xp_dirtree (and "Undocumented" procedure I think) I can have the EHR "see" the name of files "attached" to the documents.

I think you are confusing different things. Yes, YOU can (and tsql can) use that undocumented and unsupported procedure. However, your "EHR" is a system designed to provide specific functionality. It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish, but to "get" your system to do something obviously depends on your system, its features, and what you are actually trying to accomplish.

I'll add that tsql is not designed to access the filesystem natively - hence the use of undocumented extended procedures. If you are simply trying to verify or traverse this ScannedFormtable table and verify that there is some sort of file in the appropriate location, you might find this task easier to implement in a typical programming language.

If you want better suggestions, it would help to discuss your goal. And consider carefully what you are trying to do, since it is quite easy to create a security hole by altering permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It is hard for me to explain the issue, but let me try again. There are lists in the EHR that are basically queries showing rows in tables. The row in the table is called a "Scanned Document", but in reality it is almost a shell with a unique ID (in this case the field is OP__DOCID). There is a then another form that opens from the EHR using Delphi coding to create a folder on the network with the name of OP__DOCID as its name (in my previous example this would be D:\ScannedDocuments[OP__DOCID]). [continued in next comment]

Comment: Then from this delphi interface you can copy documents into that network folder. The issue is that in the list in the EHR the only thing you can see is the shell and not if any documents have actually be inserted into the network folder. This means that staff can make a shell for a scanned document, but forget to actually put anything in the folder. The only way to check the folder is to reopen the Delphi form for each individual Scanned Document shell forms. I'm hoping to be able to include in the list whether documents are in the network folder and what they are called. [continued]

Comment: Does that better clarify what my goal is? I apologize for not being more clear, it is a wonky EHR system and hard to put into words what it is doing

Comment: Not really. The problem is that you apparently want to modify the functionality of the application - and that is not likely something you can do at all (or at least with tsql). It seems you need to address this from within the application unfortunately. There might be a way to affect what is visible by hacking the mechanism that the app uses to display "the list in EHR", but that is a rather complicated discussion and requires a certain level of skill. And, of course, the application might not appreciate things appearing in some list that it doesn't understand.

Comment: Hmm, would an Execute as Owner or something like that potentially work or is that too risky a security process?

Comment: "Would it work" depends on where and how it is executed. You can use tsql and these undocumented procedures to do things, but getting this information into the application is the issue. If there is a forum specific to your app, that would be a better place for this discussion. Since you know it is Delphi, perhaps you have access to the code? If so, then it is very likely do-able.